# pandas split string column on any character that is not an alphabet

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe something like below

```
a    str_col
1    ABC*EFG
2    DDC/DSD
3.   sew^sds 
...
```

I want to split them on non alphabet and into a list. Desired df is as follows

```
a    str_col.   new_col
1    ABC*EFG.   [ABC, EFG]
2    DDC/DSD.   [DDC, DSD]
3.   sew^sds    [sew, sds]
...
```

I've tried

- `df['str_col'].str.split('^[a-zA-Z]+') but it created something like` [, *EFG]`

Comment: `df['new_col'] = df['str_col'].str.split(r'[^a-zA-Z]')` try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[^a-zA-Z]`, or `\W+` (equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`) that should also work in your case:

```
df['new_col'] = df['str_col'].str.split(r'[^a-zA-Z]+')

df['new_col'] = df['str_col'].str.split(r'\W+')
```

Output:

```
     a  str_col     new_col
0  1.0  ABC*EFG  [ABC, EFG]
1  2.0  DDC/DSD  [DDC, DSD]
2  3.0  sew^sds  [sew, sds]
```

`^[a-zA-Z]+` failed because `^` is an anchor to the start of the string when outside of `[…]`.

Comment: Perfect, having a brain fart lol. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.str.extractall`:

```
df['new_col'] = df['str_col'].str.extractall('([a-zA-Z]+)').groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Comment: You shouldn't extractall + aggregate, you can directly `df['str_col'].str.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3],
                   'str_col': ['ABC*EFG', 'DDC/DSD', 'sew^sds']})

# Split on non-alphanumeric characters, expand into lists, and keep all columns
df['new_col'] = df['str_col'].str.split(r'\W+', expand=True).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list)

"""print(df)
   a  str_col     new_col
0  1  ABC*EFG  [ABC, EFG]
1  2  DDC/DSD  [DDC, DSD]
2  3  sew^sds  [sew, sds]
"""
```